# Themeablebrowser/Themeablebrowser-wkwebview bring error during running ios .ipa

Tags: ios, ionic3, app-store, wkwebview

Due to the latest policy of app store, I need to remove the uiwebview and replace into wkwebview. I tried a lot of way and currently I stuck with the themeable browser. It seems like this plugin is the main problem as when I removed this, I achieved to upload it into the app store. Before this, my .ipa have been rejected eventually after I uploaded it in xcode. Then, (I don't know what is the cause or because of my multiple try and error experiment), the present of themeablebrowser bring error when I run the project on ipad or build it. While, before this my apps can run smoothly with it. This plugin is important for me to access another url.

Below are my code;

Uninstall & remove themeable browser

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser
npm uninstall @ionic-native/themeable-browser
```

Install and add themeablebrowser-wkwebview. Below are my codes and the error produced;

```
npm install cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser-wkwebview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser-wkwebview
```

[error archive failed - when running on ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx9yf.png)

I keep repeating the same process like removing the themeablebrowser-wkwebview plugin and add the themeablebrowser again, and get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQMdq.png)

Is there any solution regarding this? Thank you..